# Kendo grid show rtl div

Tags: jquery, filter, kendo-ui, right-to-left

I am using Kendo grid with filterable columns. When clicking filter image, a new div appears which does not have any class associated with it. My problem is adding "k-rtl" class to this div.

My Kendo grid code (brief):

```
 columns: [ {
       field: "Title",
       title: "Title",
       filterable: {
       ui: titleFilter
       }
    }
]

function titleFilter(element) {
                    element.kendoAutoComplete({
                        dataSource: titles
                    });
                }
```

Here is the generated code after clicking filter button:

```
<div>
     <div class="k-filter-help-text" ....>
     </div>
</div>
```

I want to add class="k-rtl" to parent div, something like this in jquery

```
$(".k-filter-help-text").parent().addClass("k-rtl");
```

How can I do that? The above mentioned JQuery does not work, since when document.ready() is executed, there is no such div element.

Answer (score 1):

Your initial idea is right !

You should use something like:

```
$(".k-filter-help-text").parent().addClass("k-rtl");
```

But try to make a step before..

If you haven't a div you can't add the class, then you should try to look on events. (when the div exists)

First Example on: http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Just an idea, at document.ready (when the Kendo Grid is perfectly visible, with the filter image over the columns) you should add an event handler for the click on the filter image.

```
$(document).ready(function {
    $( "identifier" ).click(function() {
        // add class code
    });
});
```

You may use ".k-grid-filter" as identifier.

I hope to be helpful, let me know !

Answer (score 0):

I had to grab click event at runtime and apply the CSS class:

```
$(".k-grid-filter").on("click", $(".k-filter-help-text").parent(), function () {
                    $(".k-filter-help-text").parent().addClass("k-rtl");
                });
```